how to watch the package received from emergency alert and information from another phone and sent back the same package to sender phone?
how to watch the package received from emergency alert or emergency information from another phone and sent back the same package to sender phone?
how to use intent to watch what another app doing such as emergency information and alert?
Is it using cellbroadcastreceiver?
how to comprehend and know what the package doing?
For example, is it the package turn on bluetooth and nfc and emergency information app or service behind?
